# Passing value from DetailTableView to MasterTableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview

In my DetailTableView users can change the label text (counter) by clicking different buttons. After clicking the back button, the MasterTableView label text should have the same value (counter). Any idea?

Comment: And what about the indexPath? Each cell labels have different values...

Answer (score 0):

To get data from DetailTableView to MasterTableView, you need to create delegate method.

Write this code in MasterViewController.h file

```
@protocol ContentDelegate <NSObject>

- (void) showMessage;

@end


@interface MasterViewController : UITableViewController
{
}

@property(nonatomic,assign) id<ContentDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

Implement ShowMessage method in Detail View Controller

```
- (void) showMessage:(NSString*)message
{
    _messageLabel.text = message;
}
```

Call delegate method from MasterViewController on table cell click

```
[_delegate showMessage:"Hello !!!"];
```

First Import MasterViewController in DetailViewController.h file
Then add ContentDelegate in DetailViewController.h file in  given form :-

```
@interface DetailViewController : UITableViewController<ContentDelegate>
{
}
```

Also set delegate self while calling MasterViewController.

Hope this solution will help you.. Thanks.

Comment: [_delegate showMessage:"Hello !!!"]; => Failure: No known instance methode for selector "showMessage"

Comment: Hi Daniela, I have edit the code, add that code to master and detail view, it will works.. Thanks.

Comment: Have updated the code but it still same failure and a warning on detail view: Method 'showMessage' in protocol 'ContentDelegate' not implemented... ???